# Order by id only count las 2 values and get the day that they have between with MYSQL in GRAILS

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

The data that is going to order by id, within the information I get from the query, I need to calulate the days between days from this query.

```
result = DEVsTACK.executeQuery("
select maintenance 
     , advisor
     , advisorId
     , DATEDIFF(managementDate, appointmentDate) AS date
     , Date
     , carKm
     , observations 
  FROM DEVsTACKAS 
 order 
    by id DESC
", [[offset:0, max:2])
```

Example:

```
    one                    two                   three
2017-04-21 12:36:10 and 2017-04-22 09:36:10 and 2017-04-26 09:36:10
```

`one` to `two` should get an answer of a day and from `two` to `three` the answer should be four days. How can I get values from a users id and see how many days are between the days I have showed from the column `date`?

Comment: I am not following you, could you please explain little more?

Comment: i need to get data from only by advisorId this colum can have multiple rows with values within those values i need to count the days between like the example i showed

Comment: given you a mark up since it may have been your English that people hadn't understood. looking at your question I clearly understood what you are trying to do. Anyhow In my answer below if you follow `internalDuration` in the codebase you will see it is being used to sort columns by. So perfect for knowing which are first last according to that value..Maybe not so human readable. Instead you can see the results returned reparsed and given a new field instance-> then had a new `instance.duration` appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use `createCriteria` [follow this link](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

you can use `maxResult`.

this is my example `createCriteria`

```
def c = PerintahKerja.createCriteria()
        def results = c.list(params) {
            if(params.noPerintah) {
                ilike("noPerintah", "%${params.noPerintah}%")
            }
            if(params.from){
                from = new Date().parse('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', params.from+" 00:00:00")
            }
            else{
                from = removeTime(from)
            }
            if(params.to){
                to = new Date().parse('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss', params.to+" 00:00:00")
            }else{
                to = removeTime(to)
            }

            ge("tanggalPerintah", from)
            le("tanggalPerintah", to)

            eq("deleteFlag", "N")
            eq("cif", cif)
        }
```

FYI, you can get range of date in `gsp`.

for example.

```
|managementDate      | appointmentDate      | countDay|
|-------------------------------------------|---------|
|2017-04-21 12:36:10 | 2017-04-22 12:36:10  | 1       |
```

after you throw this list to `gsp`.

you can do something like this to get range between two dates.

```
<%
    use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
        def duration = date1 - date2
        print "Days: ${duration.days}, Hours: ${duration.hours}, etc."
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within HQL. So as you are currently doing 'executeQuery' aka HQL query.

[First point](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueueReportService.groovy#L436) You can run specific mysql commands within HQL which will give you the difference between the two dates by default so no additional work around using timeCategory or any additional messing with results from db.

Mysql :

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(coalesce(rq.finished,rq.start)) -  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(rq.start))
```

This will then fail whilst you test your query on internal db 
So [instead](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueueReportService.groovy#L459-L461):

```
CONVERT(concat(hour(rq.finished)*60*60+minute(rq.finished)*60+second(rq.finished)) ,INTEGER) -
                CONVERT(concat(hour(rq.start)*60*60+minute(rq.start)*60+second(rq.start)) ,INTEGER)
             as internalDuration,
```

Change `rq.finished and rq.start` to your date fields `managementDate, appointmentDate`

if you want to produce [days hours months](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueueReportService.groovy#L531-L532) ago etc:

```
results=results?.each { instance ->
            TimeDuration duration=getDifference(instance?.startDate,instance?.finishDate)
            instance.duration=formatDuration(duration)
```

Which uses [getDifference](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueueReportService.groovy#L565-L576)

```
private TimeDuration getDifference(Date startDate,Date endDate) {
        if (startDate && endDate) {
            //return TimeCategory.minus(endDate, startDate)
            TimeDuration customPeriod = use(TimeCategory ) {
                customDuration( endDate - startDate )
            }
            return customPeriod
        }
    }
    TimeDuration customDuration( TimeDuration tc ) {
        new TimeDuration(  tc.days , tc.hours, tc.minutes, tc.seconds, ((tc.seconds > 0||tc.minutes > 0||tc.hours > 0) ? 0 : tc.millis))
    }
```